# How do I recalculate the values of a column based on the current value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I need to multiply the values of a column by 2.2 but only if the values are less than 30. Any help would be much appreciated

Here is what I tried. I know it is super wrong but I have no idea where to go with this. I am new to python, so forgive the really dumb question.

Values less than 30 are in kg and need to be recalculated into pounds.

```
df['Weight']=np.where(df['Weight'] > 30, df['Weight']*2.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this dataframe for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"weight": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})
```

```
   weight
0      10
1      20
2      30
3      40
4      50
```

You can use `.loc` like this:

```
df.loc[df["weight"] < 30, "weight"] = df["weight"] * 2.2
```

```
   weight
0      22
1      44
2      30
3      40
4      50
```

You can read more about selecting data [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

---

You can also use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) (not `numpy.where`):

```
df["weight"] = df.where(df["weight"] >= 30, df["weight"] * 2.2, axis=0)
```

```
   weight
0      22
1      44
2      30
3      40
4      50
```

---

Or [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df["weight"] = df.mask(df["weight"] < 30, df["weight"] * 2.2, axis=0)
```

```
   weight
0      22
1      44
2      30
3      40
4      50
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with using `np.where()`, but you need to adjust the condition and what happens when the condition is not met.

You can see the `np.where()` as an if else. If the first condition is met (i.e. df['Weight'] > 30) you update the value with the second argument (in your case multiply by 2.2). **But what if the condition isn't met ?**
That's why you need to provide a 3rd argument to the method which tells what do do if the 1st condition isn't met.

The corrected code is:

```py
df['Weight'] = np.where(df['weight'] < 30, df['weight'] * 2.2, df['weight'])
```